# Jupyterhub Unable to connect to Kernel from Web Browser

Tags: python, kernel, jupyter, jupyterhub

We have Jupyterhub installed on a Ubuntu server. Our firewall ports are not open in general, so we opened ports like 8000, 8081 and 8888 to allow the web browser reach jupyterhub. I do not know too much of administration work.

While Jupyterhub is loading, yet when we try to connect the kernel - it shows an error stating

> A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration.*

Jupyterhub Version - 0.8.0
Also we are forcing it to on a specific IP

Our logs show something like below - I am not sure what to do with that.

"shell_port": 55029,
  "iopub_port": 36663,
  "stdin_port": 42650,
  "control_port": 38954,
  "hb_port": 58009,

For the ip: 127.0.0.1

Anyone faced similar kind of error or anything